# Set android.max_aspect to unlimited?

Tags: android

I see that [new guidance](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html) is to set a value for `android.max_aspect` in your Manifest.

Is it possible to set this to unlimited (without relying on a kludge like setting it to `9999999`, and without setting `android:resizeableActivity` to `true`)?

Answer (score 1):

For all practical purposes, you don't need `unlimited` - it would be sufficient if you set it to a reasonably high value like `10`

As you might know, aspect ratio is the ratio of longer side of your display to the other side. If you think about it logically, a display with aspect ratio of `10` itself (width is 10 times height or vice versa) is going to be extremely inconvenient and impractical to design in an android device (imagine viewing your app on a device with a length of 10 times the width!)

As a side, it's poor design to even set the max_aspect to 10 - it would be difficult to test how your app behaves in a 10 aspect ratio device and you can never guess what would go wrong in UI at such extremes.

Comment: Well I agree that a very high aspect ratio display will be impractical.  That is why the manufacturers will never make one.  So what I want is to be able to specify that, for any device which a device manufacturer has committed millions into developing and marketing (and hence you can be sure it will have a sensible aspect ratio), my app will look OK on it... there is no reason why it shouldn't.  Sure I can set `max_aspect` to some arbitrarily high value but for me, that is kludgy.  I think that not setting any value for this property should mean "anything is OK".

Comment: Not setting any value would default to 1.86 - "If not set, and android:resizeableActivity is not true, the maximum aspect ratio defaults to 1.86 (roughly 16:9). To support newer widescreen devices, we recommend that you design your app to support aspect ratios of 2.1 or higher, if possible." - from https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html